# Create Multi User Chat Room in Ejabberd

Tags: php, ejabberd

Up to now I have successfully installed ejabberd and registered two user for a one-one chat. In client side i used strophe and is working fine with one-one chat. Now I am moving on to multi user chat and have to create chat room with limited users to get access to this room. What is the procedure for creating MUC ? and is there any command line interface such as "register username hostname password" as that of creating user.

Please help me out as there are no proper documentation for ejabberd and please suggest any good tutorials for creating Multi User chat.

Answer (score 10):

You have to use `mod_muc` module for multi user chat.
Check this official document,
 
http://www.process-one.net/docs/ejabberd/guide_en.html#htoc47

Comment: Thanks for you answer and sure will check out and ask for doubt.

Comment: Sure, let me know if you need help